# For real $x$ and $y$, why does $x<y$ imply that $y>x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Assume that $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$. Why does $x<y$ imply that $y>x$? Is there ever a situation when this is not true?

Comment: By definition, $<$ is the [converse binary reation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Converse_relation) of $>$ (and visa versa). Thus the proposition $\forall x,y \in \mathbb R: x < y \iff y > x$ is immediate.

Comment: The symbols $y>x$ *literally* mean $x<y$.

Comment: @azif00 why is that not circular reasoning?

Comment: @KwameBrown , either as an axiom or by whatever process one uses to construct the real numbers one already has a total ordering $<$ on $\mathbb R$. $>$ is then defined implicitly from $<$. In introductory analysis / (pre)calculus courses the existence of $<$ is taken for granted. This means that the definition is not circular.

Comment: @KwameBrown How do you define $y>x$ if NOT the converse relationship of $x<y$?  If you want an answer to your question, you'll need to provide your definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the similar question

> Does $x \leq y$ imply $y > x$?

It doesn't, because if $x = y$, then $y \not> x$. But you didn't ask about less than or equal nor greater than or equal.

Maybe it would help to think of it in terms of differences. If $x = y$, then $x - y = 0$ and $y - x = 0$ also. But if $x < y$, then $x - y$ is negative and $y - x$ is positive. If instead $x > y$, then $x - y$ is positive and $y - x$ is negative.

However, there are situations in which it would appear to be false, such as floating point arithmetic on subnormal numbers, e.g., $5 \times 10^{-324}$ in 64-bit floating point. Suppose $x$ and $y$ are subnormal numbers whose hexadecimal bit patterns differ by 0000 0000 0000 0001. Then under certain operations they might seem equal.

Answer (score 2):

The definiton of the relation "$<$" is;

$$ x<y \Leftrightarrow y-x \in \mathbb R_+. $$

The symbol "$>$" can be defined analogously. In easy terms, when we write the relation symbol backwards in $y > x$, we want to mean $x < y$. It's just to make the proofs look more structured, and visually more appealing.

Answer (score 1):

To clear your question, it depends the way you construct your real numbes.
I will let you one definition of ordering, in where you can understand the construction.

A Field (in this case, $\mathbb{R}$) is said to be ordered, if exists a set $\mathbb{P}\subset \mathbb{R}$ (P for "positive"), such that:

1. For any $x,y$ in $\mathbb{P}$, then $x+y$ and $xy$ are both in $\mathbb{P}$
2. For any real number $z$, one only one of the following is satisfied:
   $$z \in \mathbb{P}~~~~~~~~ \text{or   } ~~~~-z \in \mathbb{P}~~~~~~~~ \text{or   } ~~~~z=0$$

If you can find a set $\mathbb{P}$ with those properties, you can say that your Field ($\mathbb{R}$) has a order. Now, we proceed with the definition of the symbols "$<,\le, >,\mbox{ and } \ge$".

Let be $x,y$ any pair of numbers on your field ($\mathbb{R}$), we define the following sentences:

- we say that $x>y$ iff $x-y\in\mathbb{P}$.
- we say that $x<y$ iff $y>x$.
- we say that $x\ge y$ iff $x>y$ or $y=x$
- we say that $x\le y$ iff $y<x$ or $y=x$.

So now, the question is: what is $\mathbb{P}$?
Just look back at the definition: Let $x$ be a real number and $y$ be a fixed real number, we fix $y$ as 0, By closure of real numbers, $z=x-y$ is a real number.

So, property $2$ of set $\mathbb{P}$, applied to $z=x-y$ says that:

For any real number $z$ ,one only one of the following is satisfied:
$$z \in \mathbb{P}~~~~~~~~ \text{or   } ~~~~-z \in \mathbb{P}~~~~~~~~ \text{or   } ~~~~z=0$$
That means:
$$x-y \in \mathbb{P}~~~~~~~~ \text{or   } ~~~~-(x-y) \in \mathbb{P}~~~~~~~~ \text{or   } ~~~~(x-y)=0$$
that means that:
$$x \in \mathbb{P}~~~~~~~~ \text{or   } ~~~~-x \in \mathbb{P}~~~~~~~~ \text{or   } ~~~~x=y$$
which is the tricotomy property. Is clear that you can choose $\mathbb{P}$ as the set of numbers lower than 0 or the set of numbers greater than $0$. (Note that 0 is not in $\mathbb{P}$). Therefore, by conventionality, we choose $\mathbb{P}=\{x \in \mathbb{R}\colon x>0\}$